# how to create Laravel chart package realtime with database

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, charts

I want to create a RealTime Charts by laravel

I have 5 Tables on my database

- user
- management> has 5 managements with reletionship with users table

and I have 3 tables that users felt and all have user_id:

- palns
- projects
- activites

So i want a bar chart has the count(plans, projects, activites) for each management

My chart code in ChartController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\Management;
use Charts;
use App\Plans;
use App\Projects;
use App\Activies;
class ChartController extends Controller
{
    public function chart(){
        $chart = Charts::multi('bar', 'material')
        ->title("My Cool Chart")
        ->template("material")
        ->dimensions(0, 400) 
        ->dataset('projects', [ , , , , ])
        ->dataset('plans', [ , , , , ])
        ->dataset('activities', [ , , , , ])        
        ->labels(['management1', 'management1',
         'management3', 'management4', 'management5']);
        return view('chart',compact(''));
    }
}
```

example for chart that I want:

[image]

How can I do that and thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways:

1) Refresh the page or javascript data source repeated requests at specific time intervals. **This is bad way.**

2) Use socket. **This is good way.**

Already, laravel comes with broadcasting support for real-time actions by default. First of all, please read the [broadcasting document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting) of laravel framework. After, you should learn how can you will use socket.io for create tcp socket and real-time data watching. In the document you can find a clearly tutorial for use laravel broadcasting, for more you must learn socket.io library.